# error: unknown type name '__darwin_wctype_t' typedef __darwin_wctype_t wctype_t compiling on MacOS with Clang

Tags: c++, clang, iostream

Completely new project is totally fine, but I found pretty old opensource project and want to compile it. Basically, error appears when including headers like `iostream` or `algorythm`.

My environment looks like the following:

1. MacOS 10.15.4
2. Clang 11.0.3
3. Cmake 3.16.5
4. Tools and headers are installed here `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`
5. Project uses cotire 1.8.0
6. IDE - CLion

In general, project consists of 30+ sub-projects some are C some C++. Only those in C can be built.

I've been trying a lot of stuff: setting target version for Cmake, setting paths where to look for headers manually (in Cmake files). Re-installing developer tools does not help as well.

Please, see original error message:

```
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:214:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:118:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:92:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_wctype.h:42:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/__wctype.h:62:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types/_wctype_t.h:32:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wctype_t'
typedef __darwin_wctype_t wctype_t;
```

**UPDATE 1**
I've moved a bit forward, and figured out that `stdafx.h` cannot even include `iostream`. So I will check all include paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with includes. Project has its own `_types.h`, and there is one in system. Project's variant was included first and system's one was ignored. Obviously, this leads to such cryptic messages.

This is a root cause.Clang's documentation says I need to use `-isysroot` to explicitly set system's headers root and this will prevent matching project's header first, but it doesn't work for me. Temporarily, I changed project's header name(`types.h`) and it worked well(without underscore it is no longer considered as a system header), in the meantime I will try to fix it properly.