# Unable to compile C/C++ code calling mallinfo() on MacOS

Tags: c++, c, malloc

I need help using the `mallinfo` function in C code on a MacOS system. Despite including the `<stdlib.h>` into my source file I run into the following error compiling the code with GNU gcc ver. 12.3.0:

```
MPI/worker.C: In member function 'int64_t Worker::cmembytes1(uint64_t*)':
MPI/worker.C:181:19: error: aggregate 'Worker::cmembytes1(uint64_t*)::mallinfo minf' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  181 |   struct mallinfo minf;
      |                   ^~~~
MPI/worker.C:182:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Worker::cmembytes1(uint64_t*)::mallinfo'
  182 |   minf = mallinfo() ;
      |                   ^
MPI/worker.C:181:10: note: forward declaration of 'struct Worker::cmembytes1(uint64_t*)::mallinfo'
  181 |   struct mallinfo minf;
      |          ^~~~~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: MPI/worker.o] Error 1
```

**Update:** I suspect, that most of my problems come from mixing native macOS headers and GNU headers. The definitions clash, when I include macOS SDK for the use of `mallinfo()`.

Comment: That's C++, not C, btw.

Comment: Can you please tell me, what makes you think so?

Comment: @mabalenk Because of the `::` and member functions. You don't see that in C. It doesn't look exactly like C++ either though. Could it be Objective-C or one of the other Apple languages? I have never seen them so I don't know for sure.

Comment: No, it's definitely neither Objective-C nor an Apple language. Potentially the codebase I work on is primarily C with C++ elements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code wouldn't get that far if compiled with a C compiler though. Make `make` print out the actual compilation commands and it should tell you.

Comment: This is my compilation command: `mpicc -I. -ICore -IFileIO -I/opt/pnetcdf/include -I/opt/local/include/mpich-gcc12/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/ -g -O3 -openmp   -DLIM_METHOD1 -DLIM_METHOD2 -DPRE_FILTER -DENABLE_MPI -DDEBUG -DRANGE -DMPICH_IGNORE_CXX_SEEK -DHETERO_SUPPORT      -c -o ifm.o ifm.C`. The `mpicc` wraps around the `gcc-mp-12 (MacPorts gcc12 12.3.0_0+stdlib_flag) 12.3.0`, a GNU C compiler from MacPorts.

Comment: Ok, it's C++. _"Note that mpic++, mpicxx, and mpiCC all invoke the same underlying C++ compiler with the same options"_

Answer (score 1):

`struct mallinfo`, if it even exists on your system, is defined in `malloc.h`, so add:

```c
#include <malloc.h>
```

If it can't find that header, you can't use the `struct`.

[`mallinfo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/mallinfo.html):

> Portability problems not fixed by Gnulib:
>
> This function is missing on some platforms: macOS 11.1, FreeBSD 13.0, NetBSD 9.0, OpenBSD 6.7, Minix 3.1.8, IRIX 6.5, Solaris 11 2010-11, mingw, MSVC 14.

Comment: I can find it on my system under: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/malloc.h`, but once I include it the compiler bombards me with errors of the type `error: '__darwin_wctype_t' does not name a type; did you mean '__darwin_wchar_t'`.

Comment: @mabalenk Ok, that's the next level of the problem which needs further investigation. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61586097/7582247

Comment: It seems as an overkill, exchanging one error of `mallinfo` for dozens of `__darwin***` style errors. I'm thinking, maybe is there a MacOS analog of `mallinfo`?

Comment: @mabalenk What MacOS version are you runing?

Comment: I'm on macOS Ventura 13.4.1. I suspect, that most of my problems come from mixing native macOS headers and GNU headers. The definitions clash, when I include macOS SDK for the use of `mallinfo`.

Comment: @mabalenk Oh, ok. That may be the explanation yes. Too bad I don't have a workaround :-(